# How detailed should my manual test case be?

Tags: testing, manual-testing

I'm testing a business app and my boss insists that my test cases are too detailed and bring no value to the company. For UI and functionality testing I was just testing every text box, menu, etc., and making a proper test case in MTM.

How much detail should I include in test cases? How detailed should they be?

Comment: Is the complaint that the test cases are testing too many things, or that the test cases give instructions that are overly specific?

Comment: Both. My boss says it should be less specific and i should not test every field or menu. It's first time someone told me something like that, so I don't really know how much less specific I have to be.

Comment: A good question to ask your boss, who is going to read these test cases after you've executed them.  Try to understand how much detail that party will need.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to suggest something without seeing what you've got and what's being criticized.

Just a tiny idea on how to make your test-cases more general: ***try to make use of some kind of repositories.***

These can be UserRepository (having GoodUser, BadUser; GoodUser.Admin, GoodUser.Customer, etc).

Such strategies are applied in automation testing.

This way, instead of having

```
1. Enter "Login1" into 'login field';
2. Enter "Password1" into 'password field';
3. Press 'Sign in' button...
```

You'll simply have

```
1. Sign in as GoodUser.Customer;
```

And if you have some other field added to the login process later, you won't bother editing dozens of test-cases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write test cases in proper formation. If application is big and you are testing first time then you have to create test cases for every fields and every menus.

If you have knowledge about the application functionalities and you have also worked on it then create test cases for functionalities and include validations.

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy just follow my points:

1) Just understand that app.

2) Just understand that app functionality.

3) Note important points in that app.or note that app full functionality line by line in a paper.

4) Now Start write test cases by the functionality.

5) Your are testing business app so it is related to server side also.

6) Write some test cases server side also.

7) Write test cases clearly and step by step.Because in testing every point is important to the developers.

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new tester then try to understand the application first then ask for requirements and according to your requirement you can write test cases.
100% testing for any application is not possible,try to complete all functionality as well as write Bug sheet,which helps to improve application UI and functionality.
Don't add redundant test cases for menus,text-box,buttons etc.
I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In an application you can write a single test case for an action and records your results

EX:

For login page you can write a single case with and provide different input while doing your validation for all fields and record the results based on your requirement.